# Form group margin bottom removed

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating a nested row with some `form-group` element in a bootstrap tab panel.
Unfortunately those form-groups are not vertically spaced correctly despite to the fact that `form-group` has a `margin-bottom` of `15px` in `bootstrap.css`.
Can anybody suggest why and a solution?

Please have a look at the following [fiddle](http://www.bootply.com/HAEZwoVo67) to understand.

Thanks

Comment: can you please provide some more information  regarding issue

Comment: @RamanaaGj: have you seen the fiddle?

Comment: yes ., but  i can"t figure out what you are asking

Comment: @RamanaaGj: form-group elements have no vertical margin between them. But form-group has a css rule which apply 15px bottom margin. How can I restore that margin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you to use http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal

Take a look at [**DEMO**](http://www.bootply.com/CDsboJALx6)

---

Markup

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="ibox-content">
                <!-- Nav tabs -->
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab1</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#properties" aria-controls="properties" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab2</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <form class="form-horizontal">
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Field</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Value">
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Field</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Value">
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <form class="form-horizontal">
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Field</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Value">
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Field</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Value">
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="properties">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <input type="hidden" id="hiddenJson" value="@ViewBag.Json">
                                <div class="well" style="min-height: 190px;">some data</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Explanation. All col-* classes have float property. All float elements have no height in css, so their parents can't get height value, height: auto doesn't work.

All you need is to wrap forms correctly. Remember, you always should use .row to parent and .col-* to child.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
   <div class="ibox-content">
    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
     <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab1</a></li>
     <li role="presentation"><a href="#properties" aria-controls="properties" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
     <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
         <div class="row">
          <label class="col-md-3 control-label">field 1</label>
          <div class="col-md-9">
           <input class="form-control" type="text" value="value field 1" disabled="">
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
         <div class="row">
          <label class="col-md-3 control-label">field 2</label>
          <div class="col-md-9">
           <input class="form-control" type="text" value="value field 2" disabled="">
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
         <div class="row">
          <label class="col-md-3 control-label">field 3</label>
          <div class="col-md-9">
           <input class="form-control" type="text" value="value field 3" disabled="">
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
         <div class="row">
          <label class="col-md-3 control-label">field 4</label>
          <div class="col-md-9">
           <input class="form-control" type="text" value="value field 4" disabled="">
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="properties">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">
        <input type="hidden" id="hiddenJson" value="@ViewBag.Json">
        <div class="well" style="min-height: 190px;">some data</div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>

    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Thanks very much for the deep explanation. While in your answer you're not using a form tag, you teached me something very important about the col-* classes.

Comment: Using .col-* always with .row is one of the common rules of bootstrap.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the class mb-the value you want, see the Documentation for spacing, it fixes the issue.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/spacing/

Comment: Do you have a Iink for "Documentation for spacing"?